# Noise very slow to import

Tags: music

I'm importing my library to noise (there are about 12000 songs in my library, and it's been going 3 hours so far. It's about half way through, so likely to be totalling in the region of 6 hours. Is there anything I can do to speed up the process short of submitting a pull request to thread the library import?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I love the look and feel of Noise, but it takes too long to import a big library (~140Gb of music files, some in mp3 and the others in flac). This is the only thing that keeps me from using Noise. : ( Rhythmbox completes the scanning in less than an hour. I have an i7 (notebook) and it uses ~95% of one of the cores of the processor, and slows the response of the SO. This is not problem on it's own, but is a core used at high load for really long time, so it becomes a little anoying. PD: Sorry about my english, I'm a little rusty.

Comment: It does seem to be purely because the app is single threaded. I might look into threading it myself if I can find where the source is hosted... I guess this question becomes a feature request now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That bug/feature request is the way to go. In fact, one exists, so please [subscribe to the **bug report** here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1325361) for when the devs need help testing solutions. If you want to give the open source devs some extra incentive, try putting [a developer bounty](https://www.bountysource.com/teams/elementary/bounties) on the task. And of course, if you're interested in [writing it yourself](https://elementary.io/get-involved)...